# Delivery to specific postcodes

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to figure out how to set different shipping charges dependent on different post code areas at paypal checkout?

At the moment the courier company I use for delivery from my website charge a flat rate for most of the UK, but some islands and outlying areas are charged more for postage.

These areas are identified via their postal code, however I cant seem to find how to change the postal charges in relation to the postcode entered by the customer.

At the moment someone from an Island could easily buy and pay for something without paying extra for postage as specified on my website.

Thanks for your help......

Answer (score 0):

Look into Standard implementation of PayPal Express checkout (no callback). This way after the user completes the transaction on PayPal, he is taken back to your site and you can charge him whatever you need to based on the address from PayPal.